# Proof of $\sum_{i=0}^{2k}\binom{n}{2i}{(-1)}^i = 2^{2k}(-1)^k$ where $n=4k$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

(Suppose $n =4k$ for some positive integer $k$ )

$\sum_\limits{i=0}^{2k}\binom{n}{2i}{(-1)}^i = 2^{2k}(-1)^k$

$LHS = \binom{n}{0}-\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{4}-\binom{n}{6}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+\binom{n}{n}$

To prove above identity I had derived below identity:

$\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{2}+\cdot\cdot\cdot\binom{n}{n} = 2^{n-1}$

However, still missing how to configure each $(4k+2)$th term to be $(-1)$ coefficient.

any advice would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
(1+i)^{4k}&=& \sum_{j=0}^{4k} \binom{4k}{i} i^{j} \\
(1-i)^{4k}&=& \sum_{j=0}^{4k} \binom{4k}{i} (-i)^{j} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Add these together & use $ (1+i)^2=2i$.

Answer (score 0):

We can write,
$$(1+x)^n=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}x+\binom{n}{2}x^2+\cdots+\binom{n}{n}x^n$$$$$$

> Now put $x=i$

$$(1+i)^n=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}i+\binom{n}{2}i^2+\binom{n}{3}i^3+\cdots+\binom{n}{n}i^n$$$$$$

> Dividing and multiplying by $\sqrt{2}$ in LHS

$$(\sqrt{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}))^n=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}i+\binom{n}{2}i^2+\binom{n}{3}i^3+\cdots+\binom{n}{n}i^n$$$$$$

> Using Euler's identity $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$

$$\sqrt{2}^n(e^{i\frac{π}{4}})^n=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}i+\binom{n}{2}i^2+\binom{n}{3}i^3+\cdots+\binom{n}{n}i^n$$$$$$
$$\sqrt{2}^ne^{in\frac{π}{4}}=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}i+\binom{n}{2}i^2+\binom{n}{3}i^3+\cdots+\binom{n}{n}i^n$$$$$$

> Using Euler's identity again

$$\sqrt{2}^n\cos(\frac{nπ}{4})+i\sqrt{2}^n\sin(\frac{nπ}{4})=(\binom{n}{0}-\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{4}-\cdots)+i(\binom{n}{1}-\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n}{5}-\cdots)$$$$$$
Equating the real parts,
$$\sqrt{2}^n\cos\frac{nπ}{4}=\binom{n}{0}-\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{4}-\cdots$$$$$$
Now substitute $n=4k$ and get the answer using,
$$\binom{4k}{2k-\gamma}=\binom{4k}{2k+\gamma}$$